# How to use Key Value Coding to Set Property Values in ABPerson

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Given this key/value pair:
`FirstName = "Steve"`

I'd like to set the property of an ABPerson in the iPhone Address Book, like so:
`ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, @"Steve", nil);`

The problem is, I won't always know what key is submitted.  (It will be equivalent to a property constant without the "kABPerson" before it, and "Property" after it).
The submitted key could be any number of properties: "JobTitle", "Note", etc.
How do I translate that key into the Address Book Property Constant. ie:
`FirstName to kABPersonFirstNameProperty`.

I was thinking I could use Key Value Coding, but I'm at a loss as to how I'd implement it in this case.

For the sake of coding efficiency, I'm trying to avoid using a long `Switch` statement, or using an array filled with every possible Property.

**Update**

I'm discovering here that I need to access a constant by it's string representation.  But I don't know if that's possible.  So `kABPersonJobTitleProperty` is a constant that equals `18`.  So I would love if the following code worked:

  `NSString *fieldName = [NSString stringWithString:@"JobTitle"];
  NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"kABPerson%@Property", fieldName];`

ABRecordRef person = ABPersonCreate();
  ABRecordSetValue(person, propertyName, @"Fisherman", nil);

Of course, running this returns this warning  **passing argument 2 of 'ABRecordSetValue' makes integer from pointer without a cast**. Because the string `propertyName` is not resolving to the integer or constant it's looking for.

Can anyone see a way to make this work?

My setup is similar to the question listed here:
[Key-Value Coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379133/key-value-coding-with-objective-c)

I'm getting xml data that I have control over, and turning it into properties of an Address Book entry.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a application design question than anything else.  The way I see it with what you have, you're going to need a "long `switch` statement" *somewhere.*  Maybe the cleanest way would be in a message you send yourself with a signature like:

`- (ABPropertyID)recordPropertyFromMyEnum:(MyEnumType)property`

Consider this: if the only enumerations you have line up one-for-one with an `ABPropertyID`, why not just use `ABPropertyID` instead?

Comment: Because the properties are human-readable at some point before the data reaches me.  I'm parsing contact lists on paper that have fields like "First Name" and "Job Title".  I need to be able to resolve those into a Cocoa `kABPerson...Property`.  It seems inefficient to do a big Switch statement, although you may be right;  that may be the only way.